# Trying to refractor controllers - keep getting 404 errors on api call

Tags: c#, angular

I used to just use the SampleData controller that's created by default. Added my methods in, and it all worked perfectly.
Created a new class, pasted in the methods I wish (to split up the two models), edited the method where I call them and now I just get 404.

```
    class MakeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IVehicleService _vehicleService;


    public MakeController(IVehicleService vehicleService)
    {
        _vehicleService = vehicleService;
    }

    [Route("api/[controller]/Makes")]
    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> MakesAsync()
    {
        var data = await _vehicleService.GetMakeAsync(0, 10);

        return Ok(data);
    }
```

That would be the controller and one of the methods.

```
  GetMakes() {
   return this.http.get<Makes[]>(this.baseUrl + 'api/Make/Makes');
  }
```

And here I call the api, it used to work but now it just errors out.
The routes in startup.cs are left by default.

```
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: As a part of troubleshooting an HttpGet you can always copy/paste the url into the browser address bar (pick your favorite browser). In this case you would have seen that this does not work either which would have led you to focus on the server side code. So check 1) visibility of the controller (public/internal) and 2) if your DI is wired correctly.

Comment: I do try that while I'm debugging. I also checked most of my back-end to see if there is an issue there. Didn't realize I just forgot the public modifier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From the code you posted maybe you accidently deleted the access modifier when you added the new methods,
You need to make sure you are using a public controller e.g

```
 public class MakeController : Controller
```